# How to describe a level that is a bit harder than "a piece of cake"

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests

I am struggling to describe a process that is a bit harder than *a piece of cake* - meaning **it will take a little bit of effort to figure it out but not that hard**.

Is there any *phrase* or *slang* that I could use to make this compact and understandable?

Comment: Have you thought about whether you need to say anything at all.  Most actions worth doing at all are not ‘a piece of cake’.  But, from your account, it will be ‘straightforward’.  Why do you need to say more?  If you do, then ‘fairly straightforward’ would surely do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idiomatic expression which roughly means "*it will take a little bit of effort to figure it out but not that hard*" is "***it's not rocket science***".

TFD(idioms):

> **[it's not rocket science](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/it%27s+not+rocket+science)**
>
> [be not rocket science]
>   To not be a pursuit, activity, or endeavor
>   that requires extraordinary skill or intelligence.
>   Sure, *it took a
>   little bit of time to figure out*, but reinstalling the modem **wasn't
>   rocket science** or anything.
>
> Farlex Dictionary of Idioms. © 2015 Farlex, Inc, all rights reserved.

Answer (score 0):

A phrase:

> Quite simple

This is a step up from “piece of cake”, which might be “very simple” or “extremely simple”

If you are really concerned about precise degrees of simplicity you need to use precise language:

```
Extremely simple 
Very simple 
Simple 
Quite simple 
Not difficult
```

But slang expressions, like “a doddle”, “like falling of a log”, “a piece of cake”, “child’s play”, are impossible to rank.